# Ocassional loss of response when reading from USB serial port

Tags: c, serial-port, usb, at-command, serial-communication

I am writing and reading from a USB serial port (ttyACMx) that interfaces a modem with a processor. I have a serial communication process on the processor running linux that takes user input (modem AT commands) and writes it to the modem serial port. To receive the response I have a thread that listens on the serial port file descriptor(fd) using select() and then does a read() on the fd.

When I read from the port I expect a complete response for the AT command that I send to the modem. Which works most of the times. Occasionally I only get part of response (e.g two characters - ) I expect for the AT command that I send and there is nothing left to read (select() does not return).

My question is if there is a way to determine if my serial port receive buffer has something to read from but needs to be flushed given that I assume that the modem always sends a complete response to the processor?

Snippet of serial port receive thread and port configuration:

```
while(1)
{
  numfd = select(max_fd, &read_fd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  if(numfd > 0)
   {
     if(FD_ISSET(serial_fd, &read_fd))
     {
        ioctl(serial_fd, FIONREAD, &bytes);
        if(bytes)
        {
           num_read = read(serail_fd, buf, buf_len);
           if(num_read <=  0)
           {
              //error
           }
           else
           {
             // construct complete AT command response from buf
           }
        }
     }
   }

   where serial_fd is:

   serial_fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR|O_EXCL|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK);

   and it is configured as:

   tcflush(serial_fd, TCIOFLUSH);
   ioctl(serial_fd, TIOCGSERIAL, &serail_info_buf);
   serail_info_buf.closing_wait = ASYNC_CLOSING_WAIT_NONE;
   ioctl (serial_fd, TIOCSSERIAL, &serail_info_buf);

   tcgetattr(serial_fd, &termios_buf);

   termios_buf.c_cflag &= ~(CBAUD | CSIZE | CSTOPB | PARENB | PARODD | CRTSCTS);
   termios_buf.c_iflag &= ~(IGNCR | ICRNL | IUCLC | INPCK | IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
   termios_buf.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST | OLCUC | OCRNL | ONLCR | ONLRET);
   termios_buf.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO | ECHOE | ECHONL);

    termios_buf.c_cc[VMIN] = 2; 
    termios_buf.c_cc[VTIME] = 1; 
    termios_buf.c_cc[VEOF] = 0; 

    termios_buf.c_iflag |= IGNPAR;
    termios_buf.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    termios_buf.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    termios_buf.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    termios_buf.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    termios_buf.c_cflag |= CS8;

    cfsetispeed(&termios_buf, B115200); 
    cfsetospeed(&termios_buf, B115200);

    tcsetattr (serial_fd, TCSANOW, &termios_buf)
```

Comment: There's no such thing as data getting stuck in the receive buffer.

Comment: Thanks. What else should I look for?

Comment: This was fixed. Another process was opening the same port and so the AT command responses would get redirected to that process occassionally